# React props - passing arguments to parent

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm trying to code a dynamic list of dropdowns which work as inputs in a form and I'm trying to pass an argument back to the parent element with an onChange function but it does not work.

I've coded the Dropdown like this:

```
<Dropdown
   label="Geschäftsbereiche: "
   name="area"
   options={areas}
   value={selectedArea}
   onChange={onAccountingChange}
/>
```

I am trying to access the name attribute like I would access the value attribute, but i only get an empty string

```
<Accounting
      key={obj.id}
      selectedPercantage={obj.value}
      selectedArea={obj.area}
      selectedAccount={obj.account}
      onAccountingChange={(e) =>
        handleAccountingChange(
          e.target.value,
          e.target.name,
          obj.id,
          obj.area
        )
      }
```

/>

it works with the e.target.value so I kind of don't get why e.target.name does not work for me. Hope you guys have any ideas

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the function and check what all does event contain? Maybe the `name` that you are passing down isn't actually being added to the `Dropdown` component.

Comment: You cannot pass props to parent component. You can pass props only down the line and not up in hierarchy if you have any such need use Global State (Store) concept.

Comment: @GodWin but it works with e.target.value